# Create environment dashboard view using job dsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

can anyone point me in the right direction here:

I am using the Environment Dashboard plugin and Job DSL plugin in Jenkins.
I can manually create a view for a job using the Environment Dashboard option. I want to create the Environment Dashboard on the main Dashboard home of jenkins, and not within any folder.

I want to be able to achieve this by defining it within the Job Dsl script. Is this possible and any sample scripts I can use please?

Answer (score 0):

JobDSL provides a way to check all available API options by the URL:

```
<your-jenkins-url>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html
```

The list of the options depends on your Jenkins configuration. I see that it is possible to configure it as wrapper for some jobs:

[image: environment dashboard]